# Is it possible to set up an action-dependent autogenerated email workflow without using Designer?

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, outgoing-email

I've been trying to figure this out for a while but am stumped and would appreciate any help you can offer!

I have a list in SP that I would like to add a workflow to. The intent is that anytime I add a new item to the list (and ideally also when I edit an item in the list), SP would automatically email a predetermined group of users that an item has been added/edited. A link to the list is also desirable to have, but not a total deal breaker.

I've found some amazing tutorials for using SharePoint Designer to accomplish something like this, but I don't have access to it. Is setting up a workflow to do this possible without Designer? Or is there maybe another way to do this without a workflow (perhaps using Info Designer)?

Thanks for all of your help in advance. 
-amc

Comment: This sounds like an Alert would suffice

Answer (score 2):

No need of workflow, just setup alerts as below:

1) Go to the SharePoint library or list where you want to set the alert. If you’re looking at a view of the list or library on another page, you may have to click the title of the list or library first. For example, you may have to click Documents first to go to the Documents library.

2) Click Library or List, click Alert Me, and then click Manage My Alerts.

[image]

3) In the alert section, configure the alerts, the UI is very intuitive(see below screenshot)

[image]

Reference - [Create an alert to get notified when a file or folder changes in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-SharePoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Thank you! I feel incredibly silly, but in my defense when I googled the topic  I got tutorials for a workflow in Designer. So relieved there is an even simpler way!

Answer (score -1):

As Eric Alexander said, a list/library alert would send an email when someone adds or modifies something to a predefined user list.